# Loop to extract json from dataframe and storing in a new dataframe

Tags: python, performance, pandas

I have a dataframe (obtained from a csv saved from mysql) with several columns, and one of them consist of a string which is the representation of a json. The data looks like:

```
id   email_id     provider  raw_data       ts
1    aa@gmail.com    A      {'a':'A',   2019-23-08 00:00:00
                             'b':'B',
                             'c':'C'}
```

And what my desired output is:

```
email_id      a   b   c  
aa@gmail.com  A   B   C
```

What I have coded so far is the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import ast

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df1 = pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(len(df)):
    dict_1 = ast.literal_eval(df['raw_content'][i])
    df1 = df1.append(pd.Series(dict_1),ignore_index=True)

pd.concat([df['email_id'],df1])
```

This works but it has a very big problem: it is extremely low (it takes hours for 100k rows). How could I make this operation faster?

Comment: Would `json.loads` be any faster?  With a more limited structure it might.  Another thing to consider is doing a string join on all those `raw_data` strings, and calling `loads` once.  I haven't worked with `json` enough to know what's fast or slow in its parsing.

Comment: Yes, actually it is a little faster, thanks

Comment: Is the above exactly how your file looks?

Comment: I forgot to close the json, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got an amazing improvement thanks to stack overflow, regarding two things:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715965/add-one-row-to-pandas-dataframe
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37757844/pandas-df-locz-x-y-how-to-improve-speed

Also, as hpaulj pointed, changing to json.loads slightly increases the performance.

It went from 16 hours to 30 seconds

```
row_list = []

for i in range(len(df)):
    dict1 = {}
    dict1.update(json.loads(df.at[i,'raw_content']))
    row_list.append(dict1)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(row_list)

df2 = pd.concat([df['email_id'],df1],axis=1)
```

Comment: "got an amazing improvement thanks to stack overflow" Do you have a link to that answer?

Comment: Yes, I have edited the answer to add those links